# MS Access: Choosing Worksheet from Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm writing some code in MS Access and I reached to the point where user needs to choose on which worksheet of an Excel workbook there need to be performed some operation. I don't know, what name of this worksheet is or on which position it is placed.

I was thinking about a solution which will show user a form (as modal form) with listbox containing all sheets names'. When user click one of them form will show aside A1:J10 range (so user can choose the right one worksheet). After confirming choosen worksheet it will return as worksheet object.

Every thing was great untill I wanted to pass a object variable to the form. In openArgs I can only pass a string. I was even thinking about a class which will open this form but it's still no luck with passing object parameter.

I'm trying to avoid global/public variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you refer to "a form", you mean an Access form, right ?

Comment: of course. The only I know :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is wsObj, can't you just use wsObj.`Name` ?
Also have a look at wsObj.`CodeName`, which may be interesting as well.

Comment: I was thinkng about object version rather than object.name. Is is because when I have object I have the right one. If I have nore workbooks opened I need to to have more variables with parent obect. I think it's hardly possible to do it my way,

Answer (score 0):

IN the forms Module you can declare a property as object and then set that property once loaded. So in the form module

```
Option Explicit
Private myObj as object
Property Set DesiredWorksheet(o as object)
set myobj = o
End
```

and then in your code

```
 Load myform
    set myform.desiredworksheet = wsObj
    myform.show
```

Ahh, sorry I was writing Excel not Access!!!

```
 Docmd.openform f
 f.desiredworksheet = ws.obj
 docmd.openform f, windowmode:=acdialog
```

ought to work

Comment: Seariously? I didn't know that I can use properties in form. But in fact it's a class. Never reached this info before. I'm gonna try it :) Thanx for a hint.  so much to learn...

Comment: Ok. I was able to try yours solution. It works but there is a BUT. When I'm opening form by command `docmd.openform` I can use `windowmode:=acDialog` which cause code to stop running until opened form makes it's job. When I'm using `dim f as Form_SheetSelection set f = New Form_SheetSelection` it says that I can't load or unload this object (err 361). And when I omit `Load` it runs, opens form, perform all things, and go back to the place I called it from.

Comment: Hi there. I think I'm missing some thing. As I do `dim f as Form_myForm` and then `with f set .wbk = myWorkBookObject` it says that my f obect isn't yet initialized. When I add `New` keyword it starts to run `OpenForm` subroutine. When I try to open it with `docmd` it just opens but I don't have form objects variable. Could you please once again type it for me from begining to the end?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to send some value between objects.

**A**) Using Global vars into ACCESS Vba module

```
Global yourvariable As String
```

if you need some different value can use Variant, Single, etc.

**B**) Using Windows Register
To save value:

```
SaveSetting "yourprojectname", "Settings", "yourvariable", yourvalue
```

To retrieve value:

```
retvalue = GetSetting("yourprojectname", "Settings", "yourvariable", "your_default_value_if_not_exist")
```

**C**) Using OpenArg into Open Form command procedure

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "stDocName", acNormal, "filter_if_needed", "stlinkcriteria", acFormEdit, acWindowNormal, "arguments_forOpenArgs"
```

On destination form

```
Private Sub Form_Open(cancel as integer)
your_args=Me.OpenArgs
```

On all three possible solutions you can send more than one value using a chain with vars and values, an example:

```
myvar_mutiple="name=John Doe|address=Rua del Percebe 34|location=Madrid|phone=34 91 1234567"
```

On this example i used "pipe" (AltGr on key 1)  char to separate each var=value
Then on destination procedure only need split each pair:

```
splitvar=Split(myvar_multiple,"|")
```

With this you obtain for each "splitvar" an element like "name=John Doe"
Do again an split with "=" to obtain variable an value. For each value you can reassign the result to a local vars.
Full code example:

```
if me.OpenArgs<>"" then
   splitvar=Split(me.OpenArgs,"|")
   for x=0 to ubound(splitvar)
      tmpsplit=Split(splitvar(x),"=")
      paramvars=tmpsplit(0)
      paramvalue=tmpsplit(1)
      select case paramvars
         case "name"
            stname=paramvalue
         case "address"
            straddress=paramvalue
         case "location"
            strlocation=paramvalue
         case "phone"
            strphone=paramvalue
      end select
   next
end if
```

Some recommendations that i use for this code "multiple vars":
- always use Low Case variable or change this:

```
paramvars=tmpsplit(0)
```

by

```
paramvars=lcase(tmpsplit(0))
```

-if you need to use "=" into value you can change by other alternative char or search the first "=" form left (i used this solution instead Split)

```
paramvars=trim(lcase(left(splitvar(x),len(splitvar(x))-(len(splitvar(x))-instr(splitvar(x),"="))-1)))
```

- remember that you can send any value and can be converted on destination code. On this sample i use only String so you can use cLng or cInt etc.

Over your solution to select Sheet on excel from Access i think there are better alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for anwser. With OpenArgs i'm quite familiar. I was dreamin' (I guess - not yet tried) about solution Harassed Dad  wrote.